# JSON Summarize for Dashing List

Tags: json, ruby, associative-array, dashing

I am creating a Dashing job that pulls down some data from an API (this runs Ruby)

```
SCHEDULER.every '15m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
    url = "https://blah.com
    response = RestClient.get(url, {:Authorization => 'blahblah'})
    current_timelist = JSON.parse(response)

    acctitems = current_timelist.map do |row|
    row = {
      :label => row['member']['name'], 
      :value => row['actualHours']
    }
    end

    # Update the List widget
      send_event('timelist', { items: acctitems } )
end
```

I want to summarize based on the member name, but it lists every entry.

The JSON that is received from the API looks as follows (I have shortened this, and changed the names only), note the actualHours can be 0:

```
[
    {
        "member": {
            "name": "User 1"
        },
        "actualHours": 0.2
    },
    {
        "member": {
            "name": "User 2"
        },
        "actualHours": 1.5
    },
    {
        "member": {
            "name": "User 2"
        },
        "actualHours": 0.17
    }
]
```

I would also like to sort this so that I can have the top member at the top ect. I would also like to send a second event with the top person in the list (so they can get a gold star).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stanislav for his code as that formed the basis of the fix I managed to get working.

```
SCHEDULER.every '15m', :first_in => 0 do |job|

  url = "website.com"
  response = RestClient.get(url, {:Authorization => 'BlahBlah'})
  current_timelist = JSON.parse(response)

  time = {}
  acctitems = current_timelist.map do |row|
    key = row['member']['name']
    value = row['actualHours']

    if time[key].nil?
      time[key] = [value]
    else
      time[key].push(value)
    end
  end 

  resulttime = time.map do |result|
  result = {
    :label => result[0],
    :value => result[1].inject(:+)
  }
  end

  # Update the List widget
  send_event('timelist', { items: resulttime })
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your question, you need something like this aggregation

```
out = h.reduce({}) do |result, item|
  key = item[:member][:name]
  if result[key].nil?
    result[key] = [item[:actualHours]]
  else
    result[key].push(item[:actualHours])
  end
  result
end
```

it will return the following output

```
{"User 1"=>[0.2], "User 2"=>[1.5, 0.17]}
```

You can iterate over it and filter what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am however getting: "scheduler caught exception: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Can you provide a full trace? I guess that something wrong with your input data. Maybe you use strings instead of keys in hashes?

Comment: Because its running from Dashing, I dont get full output, but this is what I get back:
scheduler caught exception:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
C:/Dashing/monitoring/jobs/api.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Dashing/monitoring/jobs/api.rb:84:in `each'
C:/Dashing/monitoring/jobs/api.rb:84:in `reduce'
C:/Dashing/monitoring/jobs/api.rb:84:in `block in <top (required)>'

Comment: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:230:in `trigger_block'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:204:in `block in trigger'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/scheduler.rb:430:in `block in trigger_job'